# Why do my output not show in the journal?

Tags: systemd

I'm new to [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), but since its the default on my fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install, and seems to be the now defacto standard on all *nix systems I thought I might give it a try.

But I'm struggling with the output from my application.

Occasionally my app or some of the library's used will emit output on stdout or stderr. This is not my intention by not always avoidable. So to keep track of whats going on I want these messages to show up in the journal.

So for example, if I have the following in my service-file nothing gets written to the journal:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -c "print 'Hello';"
```

If I on the other hand includes an exception in the code both the initial *Hello* and the exception gets written to the journal:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python -c "print 'Hello';raise Exception('Oh noooo...');"
```

What should I do to get the *normal* stdout messages to show up in the journal?

I'm on version 229 of systemd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python buffers its output. Try to use `python -u` or aother answers found on Stack overflow.

Comment: It worked, byt why? Shouldn't the buffers be flushed when the app exits or are they just dropped?

Comment: I made a new followup question to this question: https://serverfault.com/q/849249/243665